# Is there a way to display a loading screen while waiting for an Angular 2 route to resolve?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using a `Resolve` interface to ensure a model is loaded before a component is displayed:

routes:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: PlatformComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        resolve: {
          account: AccountResolver,
        },
```

resolve:

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountResolver implements Resolve<Account> {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  resolve() {
    return this.userService.getAccount().first();
  }
}
```

app-component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <shared-spinner></shared-spinner>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
```

The `<shared-spinner>` component selector displays a loading spinner. Is there way to tell it to only render when no child component has yet rendered in the `<router-outlet>`? Or, is there another way to do this?

#### Edit:

The solution:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet><shared-spinner *ngIf="!initialized"></shared-spinner></router-outlet>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private initialized = false;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.userService.getAccount().subscribe(account => {
        if (this.initialized) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (!account) {
          return;
        }
      
        this.initialized = true;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In this manner it is quite tightly coupled to the functionality of the resolve method. I wonder if there is something simpler/cleaner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nesting the spinner tag inside of the router outlet tag, it should be replaced when a component is loaded into the router outlet.

Edit: Add the *ngIf directive to the spinner to toggle it being displayed. Components will be loaded directly after the `<router-outlet>` tags, not inside of them.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. The spinner shows up, but doesn't go away.

Comment: You can use *ngIf with a Boolean value loading to toggle between it being shown or not shown

Comment: And the conditional is `this.userService.getAccount().first()`? Yes, I suppose that could work.

Comment: You would probably have to use this.userService.getAccount.first() != null

Comment: There's actually already a `filter()` in there to ensure that, in that way we also get the `resolve()` to function correctly.

Comment: @TylerKirby but how does it work. the router appends components after `router-outlet` not inside it. and `router-outlet` it's just a directive and has no template to append the spinner in.

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine you are correct. I was mistaken when I thought it replaced the content inside of the `router-outlet` tags. The original post with the `shared-spinner` above the `router-outlet` is probably preferred.